# Echoing student ranks

Tags: php, mysql

I echo a rank of a student whose `regd` is equal to `$regd`. In fact, this is working code. However, I was advised by a friend that the MySQL statements `Distinct` and `Group By` should not be used together. But as a newbie, I could not figure out how I could implement it without using `Distinct` because it does not return rows without `Distinct`.

Can anyone suggest how I can improve this code?

```
<?php 
mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_myrank = "SELECT Distinct regd, Name_of_exam, 
                    Name_of_Student, TOTALSCORE, Rank 
             FROM (SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := TOTALSCORE), 
                          @auto, @auto := @auto + 1) AS Rank 
                   FROM (SELECT Name_of_Student, regd, 
                               Name_of_exam, SUM(Mark_score) AS TOTALSCORE 
                         FROM cixexam, (SELECT @auto := 0, 
                                               @marks := 0) AS init 
                                        GROUP BY regd 
                         ORDER BY TOTALSCORE DESC) t) AS result 
             HAVING (Name_of_exam='First Terminal Exam' OR 
                     Name_of_exam='First Term Test')";

$myrank = mysql_query($query_myrank, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$data = array();
while($row_myrank = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrank))
{
   $data[$i] = $row_myrank;
   if(isset($data[$i - 1]) 
        && $data[$i - 1]['TOTALSCORE'] == $data[$i]['TOTALSCORE'])
{
   $data[$i]['Rank'] = $j;
   }else{
     $data[$i]['Rank'] = ++$j;
}
   $i++;
}
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
 if($value['regd'] == $regd)
    {
    echo $value['Rank'];
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`? Also, I think you probably intend to filter by `Name_of_exam` within the innermost query, rather than at the outermost query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use it in a subquery, I don't see the problem. If you used both in the same query, that would be redundant. But the subquery needs to use it to obtain the required data.

Did the person give a reason as to why he/she thinks this, or was it simply a general statement?

The only thing I can think of is that DISTINCT is rather slow compared to GROUP BY: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1887953/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887953/)

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Sadly not, for I was very surprised when you said you're a "newbie", because that's some good code you got there. Intermediate to advanced, I would say. Certainly not "newbie".

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. I have been struggling with this code for a week.

Comment: I find it very confusing that `Name_of_Student`, `regd`, `Name_of_exam` are selected, but the `GROUP BY` clause only contains `regd`. I know that MySQL supports this, but I've never been able to wrap my head around what is going on. What happens if `Name_of_Student` or `Name_of_exam` aren't functionally dependent on `regd`?

Comment: Now I found out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb1252/1 - the non-FD fields seems to be picked at random. For this reason alone, I suggest including the fields in the `GROUP BY` clause (if they are FD) or specifying an aggregate in stead (`MAX` seems to work on chars).

Comment: I have got an answer to my question in stackoverflow and here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859234/how-to-improve-this-php-mysql-code/17864479?noredirect=1#17864479. Will there be another great solution which is faster and more dependable?